# Product of index with multiple elements on a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I read a text file using a linked list.

```
20 10 8

4.5 8.45 12.2

8.0 2.5 4.0

1.0 15.0 18.0

3.5 3.5 3.5

6.0 5.0 10.0
```

Each column represents, Length, Width and Height respectively.

When I read the text file, each row is treated as a single node. 
I'm trying to see if there's a way to find the product of each row, the volume?

If it's not possible, then I need to find a way to call on the values read, individually(l,w,h) from another class in which I've created a method to getVolume().

Well here's my code so far: As always thank you in advance for all your help!

---

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Runtime2 {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
        String content = new String();
        int count=0;
        File file = new File("dims.txt");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                content = sc.nextLine();
                list.add(content);
            }
            sc.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println();
        }


        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("Node " + count++ + ": ");
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
```

---

```
public class Box {  
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;

    Box(double l, double w, double h ) {
        length=l;
        width=w;
        height=h;
    }


    double getVolume() {
        double vol=length*width*height;
        return vol;
    }


    boolean isCube() {
        if(length==width && width==height) {
            System.out.println("The box is a cube.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The box is not a cube.");

        return true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double getVol(String line)
   // line = "2 3 4.5"
   String[] nums = line.split(" ");
   int len = nums.length;
   double vol = 1;
   for  (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++){
       vol*=Double.parseDouble(nums[i]);
   }
   return vol;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextDouble` thrice for each line/row: [Demo](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/idLx1T)

```
    double a, b, c;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
         a = sc.nextDouble();
         b = sc.nextDouble();
         c = sc.nextDouble();
         Box box = new Box(a, b, c);            //System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + "\n");
         System.out.println("Volm of box with dimension {" + a + "," + b + "," + c + "} is :" + 
                                 box.getVolume() + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done a good job of defining your `Box` class to encode each row of your file so far. The piece that you're missing is mapping from each line of your file to a `Box` object.

You can create a new `Box` object using the `new` operator: `new Box(l, w, h)`.

The next step is to get the length, width, and height from a line within your file. You've already figured out how to get the line into a `String` variable. The next step is to use the `String`'s [`split` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to extract the values. For example:

```
String string = "a b c";
String[] values = string.split(" ");
// values[0] now contains "a";
// values[1] now contains "b";
// values[2] now contains "c";
```

Finally, use the `List` [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) method to append the new `Box to your list. I recommend structuring your code so that the file reading is encapsulated within its own method, so you might try something like this:

```
public class Runtime2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        List<Box> boxes = readBoxesFromFile(new File("dims.txt"));

        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Box " + i + " volume: "  
                + boxes.get(i).getVolume());
        }
    }

    private static List<Box> readBoxesFromFile(File file) {
        List<Box> boxes = new LinkedList<Box>();

        /*
         * - Create File object
         * - Create Scanner for File
         * - For each line in the file
         *      Split the line into a string array
         *      Create a 'Box' instance
         *      Add the Box to your list
         */

        return boxes;
    }

}
```

I've omitted the imports, and the definition of the `Box` class for Brevity, but you've already got those defined within your question.

With that in mind, try putting these pieces together to construct your method for converting your file into a `List` of `Box` objects.